# How to wrap text of results of mysqli select query

Tags: php, html

Im not even sure what to ask.

I have this code

```
$limitValue = $_POST['count'];
$type = $_POST['topic'];
$qType = join("','", $type);
$sql = "SELECT question_id, questionType, question, answerA, answerB, answerC, answerD
FROM questions
WHERE questionType IN ('$qType')
ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT $limitValue";
$result  = mysqli_query($link, $sql);

if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
// output data from each row
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    $qID = $row['question_id'];
    $a = $row['answerA'];
    $b = $row['answerB'];
    $c = $row['answerC'];
    $d = $row['answerD'];
    $rA = $row['rightAnswer'];
    echo "QID: " . $row["question_id"]. "<br>".
    "Question Type: " . $row["questionType"]. "<br><br>" .
    "Question: " . $row["question"]. "<br><br><br>";
    echo "<input type = 'Radio' Name = 'Answer[$qID]' value ='A' > A. <span><span> $a &nbsp;&nbsp;\r\n<br><br>";
    echo "<input type = 'Radio' Name = 'Answer[$qID]' value ='B' > B. <span><span> $b &nbsp;&nbsp;\r\n<br><br>";
    echo "<input type = 'Radio' Name = 'Answer[$qID]' value ='C' > C. <span><span> $c &nbsp;&nbsp;\r\n<br><br>";
    echo "<input type = 'Radio' Name = 'Answer[$qID]' value ='D' > D. <span><span> $d &nbsp;&nbsp;\r\n<br><br><br><hr>";

    /* echo "A) " .$row["answerA"]. "<br>" . "B) " .$row["answerB"]. "<br>" . "C) " .$row["answerC"].  "<br>" . "D) " .$row["answerD"]. "<br><br><br>";*/
}
}
mysqli_free_result($result);
echo "<input name='submit' type='submit' value='See Results'>\r\n";
mysqli_close($link);
?>
```

When the output is too long, it puts it on the next line away from the radio button. Like you see here with option A.

[How to wrap text?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XPINN.png)

Comment: You have two `<span><span>` tags in there which you don't close (with `</span>` tags), which is invalid HTML. That might not be related directly to your problem, but remove these to see what happens. Anyways, it looks as if the text after the input tags is defined as `display: inline-block` –  should be `inline` instead.

Comment: removing the <span><span> didn't do anything. So I guess you're right I don't need that anyway. Still getting the text forced to the next line though. How do I change it from display: inline-block to inline?

Comment: @JoshuaThornburg someone posted an answer below and I think your comment above should have been placed under it also and to inform them that what they gave you didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

It will push to next line because you have given `<span><span>` next to `A.`.  Instead of `<span><span>` try `&nbsp;&nbsp;`.  This will give you non-breaking-space.

Comment: I removed all of that and tried replace it with &nbsp;&nbsp; and that didn't work. I also removed all the formatting and it seems to have no effect on the formatting at all.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in the data base. Some people input stuff into the database and it results in paragraph breaks, (

). So the code was fine, just the data was the issue. Thanks for those that helped.